# PHP server change between Apache and Nginx: 3x performance loss

Tags: php, nginx

Our current infra works fine with Apache + PHP and MySQL managed elsewhere. I have not done any particular optimization on this server. These are the initial configurations. Except for memory_limit and execution_time.
I am in the process of changing our infra to something more modern with bigger server and Nginx + PHP-FPM.

While working on this problem, I realize that we have big performance losses using this new infra. It's a shame to have more powerful servers and it's slower.

I watched the server load and nothing. Memory and CPU are barely 2%

I pulled out my Inspector badge and began to eliminate guesswork. Obviously, my tests use exactly the same case, same framework, same version of our app, ...

Here are my tests:

1. **I installed on newer Apache + PHP servers** and in fact Apache is even slower than with Nginx (no surprise :)).
2. **I created a simple "hello wok" PHP file** to test if it could come from Nginx. So I am not using our framework which could be involved.
   Everything is normal TTFB times are almost equivalent (~ 24ms). Nginx on the new infra is 2ms faster.
3. **While going with our framework, I added a piece of basic code** which amounts to doing a "Hello wok" but using our framework.
   Ah there, we have a problem. Finally ! Old infra 61ms, New infra: 184ms.
   **The new infra is therefore 3x slower to load the framework.**

Obviously, I did a lot of optimizing the existing code but seeing that, I'll never be able to optimize it and make it 3x faster.
In all cases: Why the same code takes 3x longer to run on different environments.

The only thing that occurs to me right now is a PHP and PHP-FPM configuration problem.
**In these configurations, do you know of any reasons that could have such a slowdown?**

Obviously I looked for and tested things to optimize but it's always the same.
Here is my php.ini file:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Paris

opcache.enable = 0

apc.enabled = 1
apc.enable_cli = 1

upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128M

realpath_cache_size=4096k
realpath_cache_ttl=7200

display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_STRICT

; output_buffering=4096

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_requests = 1000

max_execution_time=600
memory_limit = 2048M

opcache.enable = 1
opcache.enable_cli = 1
opcache.memory_consumption = 2048
; opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 32
; opcache.max_accelerated_files = 100000
; opcache.max_wasted_percentage = 15
opcache.revalidate_freq = 0
; opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
```

Do you have any advice ? recommendations ? ideas ?

thanks in advance
Are you doing well

EDIT #1

**Server Information:**

*Old server:*

```
VM with 1 processor / 2GB RAM
No database, just Apache + PHP
Framework specific cache system: file
```

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 6
model name  : Common KVM processor
cpu MHz     : 3504.002
cache size  : 4096 KB
[...]
```

*New server:*

```
Docker container on a 3 processor / 4GB RAM server
I do not have the speeds of each processor. This is vCPU.
No database
Container PHP-FPM + Container Nginx
Framework specific cache system: APC
```

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 23
model           : 1
model name      : AMD EPYC 7281 16-Core Processor
stepping        : 2
cpu MHz         : 2096.062
cache size      : 512 KB
[...]
processor       : 1
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 23
model           : 1
model name      : AMD EPYC 7281 16-Core Processor
stepping        : 2
cpu MHz         : 2096.062
cache size      : 512 KB
[...]
processor       : 2
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 23
model           : 1
model name      : AMD EPYC 7281 16-Core Processor
stepping        : 2
cpu MHz         : 2096.062
cache size      : 512 KB
[...]
```

*Others :*
The database is managed in a provider
The sessions are stored in the database

Comment: Is your new server a physical server or a VM ?

Comment: How many files are loaded in the process of loading the framework? Do you have opcache enabled?

Comment: @ken Lee
The current server is on a VM.
The new server works with Docker.

Comment: What are old and new infrastructures CPUs (especially singlecore clock speed)? What OS/Kernel versions? Any network services (DB/Redis/..) that could bottleneck? PHP Sessions on slow filesystem ?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol
For the number of files loaded into the framework, this is a very good question. I do not know how to determine it precisely but not bad I think, maybe 50.
Opcahe is enabled on both but I only tried to optimize it on the new server

Comment: @Tobias K.
I just updated the post with the requested information on the servers

Comment: Do you have information on whether your new server (Docker based) is actually one physical server which is shared amongst several customers ? How many such customers are using the server at the same time ? Will it be true that one (or more) of the customers are currently engaging in heavy CPU / IO resource consumption activities ?

Comment: @ken-lee
To be honest, the new server is a Kubernetes cluster hosted by a provider made up of 2 nodes. Each node is made up of an instance of the provider (3vCPU, 4GB of RAM, a dedicated NVMe physical hard disk).

On the current PROD server, usage is fairly light, around 100 simultaneous users maximum.
On the new server (= the new cluster), there is currently no user to connect to it. I am the only one to access it, to do the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Despite what you will read all over the internet, under low loads, Apache+mod_php is significantly faster than nginx+php-fpm. The latter architecture offers better capacity and scaling. That does not explain the difference in performance reported here.

The *only* thing you have told us about the two infrastructures is that one is old and one is new. If all you know about them is that you clicked a button in a cloud control panel then it can be difficult to find out more (if this is a Linux VM, check /proc/cpuinfo and mpstat paying particular attention to the steal time). The metrics you measured by testing will be highly dependent on single thread performance which is not a good indicator of throughput on a multi-cpu machine or any machine under heavy load.

But the first place I would be looking is at the storage latency / increasing opcache.revalidate_freq.

Comment: This is indeed good to know for the difference between Apache and Nginx when you have little load.

I just updated the main post with the `/ proc / cpuinfo` information. I have the impression that the new server has more processor months but MHz per core.
On the other hand, I will be surprised that this is really a real impact because my HTTP requests on the current server do not exceed 10% of CPU.

I will try by modifying the option `opcache.revalidate_freq`. I'll get back to you.